# Not able to get search results exact position in listview in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

All my contacts ID are sitting in an arraylist called ContactsID and it's name is stored in another arraylist called ContactsName. I am displaying the name on a list view with search functionality

search function is also working fine with the help of filter.

I am trying to get the email address from contact using the position of item clicked.

Something like this:

```
  String Cid = ContactsID.get(position);
```

My query for fetching email using id works fine too (when i don't search anything)..

My only  problem is if I search for a "name" the listview gets filtered with names. results are shown on the listview but the positions are not getting updated according to it's name. It always starts from position 0 for which I will have problem in getting the contactsID for EMAIL.

So I tried parent.getItemAtPosition(position) (This gets the name of the item clicked but doesn't get the ContactsID arraylist position)

Here is what I am trying.

```
 lisview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
        {
            String Cid= contactsID.get(position);

            /*String SSid = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Log.e("ABC",""+SSid);*/

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur1 = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{Cid}, null); 


            while (cur1.moveToNext()) 
            { 
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("email",""+email);

            }

            cur1.close();
        }

    });
```

Can somebody help me out with fixing this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you have two lists, but the `ArrayAdapter` filtering mechanism only works on the list attached to the `ListView`.  So when you start filtering the list the mapping from one list to the other by position breaks down because only the list attached to the view is being modified.

The simplest solution is to create a basic POJO model object to bind the two data elements together and let your adapter manage that instead.  For example:

**ContactModel.java**

```
public class ContactModel {
    public String id;
    public String name;

    public ContactModel(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Doing this allows the adapter to display the name without
    // creating a custom getView() implementation
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

...then you can house all your data in a single `ArrayList<ContactModel>`...

```
ArrayList<ContactModel> ContactsList = new ArrayList<ContactModel>();
//Add your items
ContactsList.add( new ContactModel(someId, someName) );
```

...and modify your adapter type to be `ArrayAdapter<ContactModel>`.  Then in your click listener...

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) 
    {
        ContactModel item = ContactsList.get(position);
        String Cid = item.id;

        /** existing code, etc. **/
    }
```

This way the names displayed in the list and the ids you need for the queries are always tied together.